# Create a multiband constant Image from a list object

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I get values as a list from another computation and I would like to create an `ee.Image` with 1 band for each value.

I wanted to do it as specified in the documentation:

```js
var list = ee.List([1,2,3])
var image = ee.Image(list)
var buffer = geometry.buffer(1)
var values = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), buffer, 1)
print(values)
```

but I get the following error:

> A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations

If I use the `getInfo()` method on `list` it works but I would like to avoid client side operation, is there another way ?

Here is the example with the point geometry: https://code.earthengine.google.com/11a69463743086cf20709ab359d8289c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To instantiate a multi-band constant image using an `ee.List`, you'll need to use `ee.Image.constant` instead of `ee.Image`.

```js
var list = ee.List([1,2,3]);
var image = ee.Image.constant(list);  // Works!
var bad_image = ee.Image(list);       // Doesn't work :(
```

I suspect this is unintended behavior since the `ee.Image` constructor works as a shortcut for creating constant images in most cases including with client-side lists, but it's an easy workaround at least.

Comment: thanks I t though constant was only accepting Array and numbers, I should have tried. 
It's mentioned in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-constant